# SQL SELECT depending on value

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, select

I need advise or an idea how to solve my problem. 
I have select based on few joins.
One of the selected value is ex. `CA.PADDING_ZERO_FLAG` which is '0' or '1'.

Based on this, I want to get other values in select statement.

Pseudocode:

```
Select if(CA.PADDING_ZERO_FLAG = '1') then LPAD(ZR.START_ZIP_CODE, 5, '0'),
    LPAD(ZR.END_ZIP_CODE, 5, '0') else ZR.START_ZIP_CODE, ZR.END_ZIP_CODE
```

Is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the [Case statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) will suit your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Case statement will work for this.

```
SELECT
  CASE
     WHEN CA.PADDING_ZERO_FLAG = '1' 
         THEN 
             LPAD(ZR.START_ZIP_CODE, 5, '0')
         ELSE 
             ZR.START_ZIP_CODE
  END as 'START_ZIP_CODE',
  CASE
     WHEN CA.PADDING_ZERO_FLAG = '1' 
         THEN 
             LPAD(ZR.END_ZIP_CODE, 5,'0')
         ELSE 
             ZR.END_ZIP_CODE
  END as 'END_ZIP_CODE'
```

Comment: I guess that your query is faulty, you can't have more than one column in the single case statement

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I should have had them separateded out into a case statement for each column... It has been edited.

Comment: You're right. I also need to call function TO_CHAR on zip codes, inside case's because they are NUMBER data types and change the column identifiers to double quotes eg. END as "START_ZIP_CODE"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **decode** function

```
select 
  decode(CA.PADDING_ZERO_FLAG,
      '1', LPAD(ZR.START_ZIP_CODE, 5, '0'),
      '0', ZR.START_ZIP_CODE) START_ZIP_CODE,
  decode(CA.PADDING_ZERO_FLAG,
      '1', LPAD(ZR.END_ZIP_CODE, 5, '0'),
      '0', ZR.END_ZIP_CODE) END_ZIP_CODE
      ...
```